# How to show that the set $A=[a,b)$ is not open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I only have the definition that a set $B$ is open if for all $x \in B$, there exists $\epsilon > 0 $ such that there is an open ball centered at $x$ and radius $\epsilon$ which is a subset of $B$.

First, I want proof by contradiction to show that $A$ is not open. Suppose that it is open, thus I must let $x \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$. How do I show that there exists an open ball centered at $x$ and radius $\epsilon$ which is a subset of $A$? My main issue is how to get a good choice for $\epsilon$?

Similarly, to show that $A$ is not closed, I want to show that its complement $A^c$ is open, by a definition. Is it enough to show that $(-\infty, a)$ is open?

Answer (score 0):

To prove the set is not open you must prove that there is at least one point in the set such that there is no $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the point that it is contained in the set. To do this consider the point $a \in [a,b)$. Then any $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $a$ can not be contained in $[a,b)$, and hence $[a,b)$ is not open.

If a set is not closed then its complement is not open. You wrote that you want to prove that the complement is open, but this is not correct. The complement of $[a,b)$ is $(-\infty,a) \cup [b,\infty)$. Here again, no $\epsilon$ neighborhood exists at b such that it is contained in the set. This implies that the complement of $[a,b)$ is not open, and hence that $[a,b)$ is not closed.